# SSL module not available

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install some Python modules but this error appears:

```
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Could not find a version that statisfies the requirement module.py (from versions: )
No matching distribution found
```

I already searched for a solution (using `--trusted-host` and installing other packages), but it didn't solve the problem.

Python version: 3.6.2

pip version: 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

`pip install <packagename>` always works for me. But if you can't download it using pip then I suggest that you search for the module on Google, manually download and extract it to the directory where your python is stored.

Comment: should I extract the module in /Python-x.x/Modules?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain but you should extract the module in `/Python-x.x/Lib/<modulename>`

In other words, when you extract the module, you should get a folder. Put that folder in `/Python-x.x/Lib` directory.